# Two types of kNN classifier algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

The following is copy-pasted from a lecture note on machine learning...

> k-NN classification can be realized in two ways:
>
> 1. Selecting for the classified sample it's $k$ nearest neighbors for each class and computing than neighborhood radius $r_i$ for each of the classes. As the result of the classification, we select class $i$, for which its radius $r_i$ is the smallest.
> 2. Selecting for the classified sample it's $k$ nearest neighbors in the training set (without taking class labels into account in this step). As the result of classification, we select class $i$ which is most numerous in the set of $k$ nearest neighbors of the classified sample.

Can anyone explain what points (1) and (2) talking about?

Are they talking about *kNN for classification* and *kNN for regression*, or something else?

Comment: Could you please post where you found those notes?

Comment: @Dave, No. The source is privacy protected.

Comment: Then what is $r_i?$ Is it how wide the circle around those $k$ points has to be to contain all $k$ plus the point we are trying to classify?

Comment: @Dave, $r_i$ is the neighborhood radius of $i$-th neighbor of a class, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point #2 is the kNN I learned. It means that you look at the $k$ nearest points, say $7$, and make the classification based on those. If $5/7$ are $\text{cat}$ and $2/7$ are $\text{dog}$, you would predict a $\text{dog}$.$^{\dagger}$

Point #1 means that you select the $7$ nearest cats and the $7$ nearest dogs. I do not know what $r_i$ means, but perhaps that is defined elsewhere in the notes. Calculate $r_i$ for those $7$ cats and those $7$ dogs. Which $r_i$ is smallest of the $14?$ That class to which that belongs is the predicted class.

$^{\dagger}$[Better yet, predict a $5/7$ probability of being a cat and a $2/7$ probability of being a dog.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/247274)